# anchor links or buttons in options of select button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drop-down-menu

Hi I am doing an angular js project

I need to add anchor link or any type of button in the options field of select button.

It is not possible to add such elements in select element it self.
I found a library for drop down with checkboxes in jquery, some thing similar will do.
Is there any good library for it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Could use a popover from UI Bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)